# How can I check whether a function call results in a warning?

Tags: r

In R, how can I determine whether a function call results in a warning?

That is, after calling the function I would like to know whether that instance of the call yielded a warning.

Comment: Closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361 that provides some excellent answers with error catching as well.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you want to use the `try` constructs, you can set the options for warn. See also `?options`. Better is to use `tryCatch()` :

```
x <- function(i){
  if (i < 10) warning("A warning")
  i
}

tt <- tryCatch(x(5),error=function(e) e, warning=function(w) w)

tt2 <- tryCatch(x(15),error=function(e) e, warning=function(w) w)

tt
## <simpleWarning in x(5): A warning>

tt2
## [1] 15

if(is(tt,"warning")) print("KOOKOO")
## [1] "KOOKOO"

if(is(tt2,"warning")) print("KOOKOO")
```

To get both the result and the warning :

```
tryCatch(x(5),warning=function(w) return(list(x(5),w)))

## [[1]]
## [1] 5
## 
## [[2]]
## <simpleWarning in x(5): A warning>
```

Using  `try`

```
op <- options(warn=2)

tt <- try(x())
ifelse(is(tt,"try-error"),"There was a warning or an error","OK")
options(op)
```

Comment: thanks for your edit showing how to get both the result and the warning; however, the function is called twice when there's a warning.  Can it be done with only one call (in case the function is slow, for example)?

Comment: @Aaron : then I'd go for the handlers as shown below by you. That's the cleanest way, and those are made to do that. It just requires a bit more puzzling.

Comment: Thanks.  It is definitely puzzling.  Though it does what I need, there's a lot in that code I don't yet understand.

Answer (score 32):

On the R-help mailing list (see http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/06/0217.html), Luke Tierney wrote:

"If you want to write a function that computes a value and collects all
warning you could do it like this:

```
withWarnings <- function(expr) {
    myWarnings <- NULL
    wHandler <- function(w) {
        myWarnings <<- c(myWarnings, list(w))
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    val <- withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = wHandler)
    list(value = val, warnings = myWarnings)
}
```

Comment: Yup, that way it updates the `myWarnings` outside the function; otherwise it makes a new `myWarnings` inside the function and the outside one doesn't get updated.

Comment: This is such an excellent solution that I keep coming back to.

Comment: @Therkel, perhaps this would be of value then too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Answer (score 11):

**2019 update**

You can you use 'quietly' from the purrr package, which returns a list of output, result, warning and message. You can then extract each element by name. For instance, if you had a list, which you want to map a function over, and find the elements which returned a warning you could do

```
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

datelist <- list(a = "12/12/2002", b = "12-12-2003", c = "24-03-2005")

# get all the everything
quiet_list <- map(datelist, quietly(mdy))

# find the elements which produced warnings
quiet_list %>% map("warnings") %>% keep(~ !is.null(.))

# or 
quiet_list %>% keep(~ length(.$warnings) != 0)
```

For this example it's quite trivial, but for a long list of dataframes where the NAs might be hard to spot, this is quite useful.

Comment: Your first statement is not accurate, quietly does not handle errors see https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/quietly.html

Comment: @pietrodito thanks for the heads up, I've edited my answer. Maybe they changed the return values since 2019 or maybe I just had it wrong. Either way it's corrected now, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

here is an example:

```
testit <- function() warning("testit") # function that generates warning.

assign("last.warning", NULL, envir = baseenv()) # clear the previous warning

testit() # run it

if(length(warnings())>0){ # or !is.null(warnings())
    print("something happened")
}
```

maybe this is somehow indirect, but i don't know the more straightforward way.

Comment: Although this is inelegant, it's good because I can't find any other way to catch a warning and nevertheless return the normal result from the function. That is, if testit() returns a value, catching a warning with tryExcept means you lose the value. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @Alex : you could do pretty easily using a tryCatch formula. You can do something with the warning in the argument, eg: warning=function(w) {...do something ... return(normal result)}

Comment: @Joris: I couldn't get tryCatch to return the normal result.  Am I missing something?  I did find a way using withCallingHandlers, from the R mailing list (included as a separate answer).

Comment: @AlexHolcombe You could also set `options(warn=1)` in which case the warnings are printed to `stdout` rather than `stderr`.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the old good `sink` redirected into a text connection:

```
# create a new text connection directed into a variable called 'messages'
con <- textConnection("messages","w")
# sink all messages (i.e. warnings and errors) into that connection
sink(con,type = "message")
# a sample warning-generating function
test.fun <- function() {
    warning("Your warning.")
    return("Regular output.")
}
output <- test.fun()
# close the sink
sink(type="message")
# close the connection
close(con)
# if the word 'Warning' appears in messages than there has been a warning
warns <- paste(messages,collapse=" ")
if(grepl("Warning",warns)) {
    print(warns)
}
# [1] "Warning message: In test.fun() : Your warning."
print(output)
# [1] "Regular output."
```

Possibly more straightforward and cleaner than the other suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple `TRUE`/`FALSE` return on whether a given operation results in a warning (or error), you could use the `is.error` function from the `berryFunctions` [package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=berryFunctions), after first setting `options(warn = 2)` so that warnings are converted to errors.

E.g.,

```
options(warn = 2)
berryFunctions::is.error(as.numeric("x")) # TRUE
berryFunctions::is.error(as.numeric("3")) # FALSE
```

If you want to limit the option change to the use of this function, you could just create a new function as follows.

```
is.warningorerror <- function(x) {
 op <- options()
 on.exit(options(op))
 options(warn = 2)
 berryFunctions::is.error(x)
}

is.warningorerror(as.numeric("x")) # TRUE
options("warn") # still 0 (default)
```