# get indication of warnings in R sciript

Tags: r

I am running a glm() function nested in for() function. The output of the glm is entered into a matrix. For some of the cycles there is a warning but i get all the warnings only at the end of all the cycles so i can not know which cycle was bad. I would like to get an indication if there is a warning after each glm calculation so i can tell the script not to enter this cycle result to the matrix. Any ideas how to do this?
example:

```
   m<-matrix(nc=1,nr=100)
   for(i in 1:100){      
   fit<-glm(y~x+v1+v2+v3,data=data)
   if("there is a warning???"){
   m[i,1]<-NA
   }
   else{
   m[i,1]<-fit$coefficients[2,1]
   }
    "reset warning???"
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning

Comment: When I need to do this I store the result and all warnings and errors in a list and then process the warnings afterwards, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that sometimes warns but always returns a value

```
f <- function() {
    r <- runif(1)
    if (r > 1) warning("high")
    Sys.sleep(.1)  # 'expensive' calculation after warning
    r
}
```

The following loop is meant to update `x[i]` with the value returned by `f()`. Caught warnings are replaced by NA; the part of `f` after the warning is not evaluated. We're not interested in processing the warning message so we ignore the argument provided to the warning handler.

```
x <- numeric(10)
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    x[i] <- tryCatch(f(), warning=function(...) NA)
}
```

So for instance

```
> set.seed(123)
> system.time(x <- replicate(100, tryCatch(f(), warning=function(...) NA)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.052   0.000   8.364 
> table(is.na(x))

FALSE  TRUE 
   83    17
```

It's hard to reproduce your particular question, because `data` is not provided. I think you want to do

```
m <- matrix(ncol=1, nrow=100)
for(i in 1:100) {
    m[i,1] <- tryCatch({
        fit <- glm(y~x+v1+v2+v3, data=data)
        fit$coefficients[2, 1]
    }, warning=function(...) NA)
}
```

Comment: thank you Martin, the tryCatch() is what i needed.  The output of glm is a list and of warning in your example is NA. Therefore I filtered the  desired output by asking is.list() as follows:

Comment: `m<-matrix(nc=1,nr=100)
   for(i in 1:100){      
   fit<-tryCatch(glm(y~x+v1+v2+v3,data=data),warning=function(...) NA)
   if(is.list(fit)){
   m[i,1]<-fit$coefficients[2,1]
   }
    }`

Comment: @hans I tried to illustrate your case more directly in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that fabulous link given in the comment above by eddi, you could try the combination of making warnings to errors and jump into the function at an error:

```
options(warn = 2) # will turn warnings into errors
options(error = recover) # will allow you to browser() at the error.
```

Depending on the size of your problem the option given in the link above could nevertheless be better. But my solution is fairly easy to implement.