# Multiple expectations with test_that

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

Is there a way to have multiple for expections for an expect_that unit test?  For instance, for a given `expect_that()` statement, I'd like to expect that the function `f()` gives a warning and also returns the number `10`.

Answer (score 2):

```
test_that("f works as expected", {
expect_warning(f())
expect_equal(f(), 10)
}
)
```

If I understand your context correctly, this should work. The test would fail and report if either or both of the expectations weren't met.

To run the function only once, you could try wrapping the function within the test_that:

```
    test_that("f works as expected", {
a <- tryCatch(f(), warning=function(w) return(list(f(), w)))
expect_equal(a[[2]], "warning text")
expect_equal(a[[1]], 10)
rm(a)
}
)
```

I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it'll work in your particular case, but I've used similar approaches with test_that in the past.

Comment: `f()` takes about 10 minutes to run, so I'm looking for a way to test both outcomes (equal to 10 and gives warning) with out having to run `f()` twice.

Comment: This is still calling `f()` twice though

Comment: No it isn't. f() is called and the output assigned to a. Then a is called for the tests

Comment: I guess I mean in the event that a warning is given, it looks like f() will be called twice.

Comment: I think you are correct. Try following the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning

Answer (score 2):

```
context("Checking blah")

test_that("blah works",{
    f <- function(){warning("blah"); return(10)}
    expect_warning(x <- f())
    expect_equal(x, 10)
})
```

You can save the output while checking for the warning.  After that check that the output is what you expect.

Comment: Can you explain why `x` is available outside `expect_warning`?  I would've thought that `x <- f()` would be executed within the context of `expect_warning`, and that the `x` would not be available to pass to the subsequent `expect_equal` function.  Additionally, what if it is not as easy as saving the output of `f()`?  For instance, if I wanted confirm that neither warnings nor errors were thrown.