# tryCatch store flag and store indices where error occured

Tags: r

I'm not really understanding how `tryCatch` works. Especially the last part where you store your error message. There are a lot of posts on Stackoverflow about how to use `tryCatch`, but the solutions generally just post an error message and then move on. I'd like to store the indices of the for loop where the errors occurred so I can go back to them easily later. I'm thinking about something as follows using tryCatch

```
  flag = NULL

    for(i in 1:10) { 
      do something that can cause an error
      if (error occurs) flag=c(flag,i) and move on to the next iteration
    }
```

Ideally I'd like `flag` to store the indices during the errors.

Comment: if you're doing `for(i:10)` then I'm assuming `i` is a constant.  Are you trying to do `for(i in 1:10)` or something similar?  Also, did you read through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/2573061)?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes see correction

Comment: Here's what I do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673

Answer (score 3):

You might have to use `<<-` to assign to the parent environment, although this is probably considered poor practice. For example:

```
a <- as.list(1:3)
flag <- integer()
for (i in 1L:5L){
  tryCatch(
    {
      print(a[[i]])
    },
    error=function(err){
      message('On iteration ',i, ' there was an error: ',err)
      flag <<-c(flag,i)
    }
  )
}
print(flag)
```

Returns:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
On iteration 4 there was an error: Error in a[[i]]: subscript out of bounds

On iteration 5 there was an error: Error in a[[i]]: subscript out of bounds

> print(flag)
[1] 4 5
```

Does that help?

Comment: Not too poor practice; Luke Tierney recommended a version of this on the R-help mailing list once. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947528/210673 for his code, which collects warnings, and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948361/210673 for a version that collects errors too.