# How to see if R returns a warning but won't output it to the screen?

Tags: c#, r, r.net

I was doing computation or C# and R.net.  I would like to do the computations such that it won't output warnings or results to screen but saves them to the variables. I found that the C# won't output the result to the screen if I set                 `engine.AutoPrint = false;`I there something similar to warnings as the script outputs them automatically? Or is there some r-code such that

```
if f(data,param1) does not output a warning 
    output f(data,param1) 
else 
    output f(data,param2)
```

I tried `options(warn=-1)` but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: this might help some: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning

Comment: It helps although it seems a bit weird to write several nested tryCatches in complex cases.

Comment: Hm, I found an alternative function which looks pretty neat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903157/how-can-i-check-whether-a-function-call-results-in-a-warning/4947528#4947528. Using `withWarnings() `you can check whether the warning message is empty or not and handle accordingly