# Why tryCatch returns no warnings when it was asked for producing them?

Tags: r, testthat

Check the following example:

```
library(testthat)
expect_warning(tryCatch(stop("Error!"), error = function(e) warning(e)))
## Error: tryCatch(stop("Error!"), error = function(e) warning(e)) showed 0 warnings
## In addition: Warning message:
## In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : Error!
```

Why does testthat say that there was no warnings?

Using the [`withWarnings` function discussed in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4947528/3986320) also shows no sign of warnings. Why `tryCatch` does not produce warnings if it was asked for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created nested calls to `doTryCatch` and `withCallingHandlers`. The problem is that `e` is not a character, but a `simpleError` object (which contains another call to `doTryCatch`). The following somewhat works, but shows the actual context where the warning was thrown:

```
tryCatch(stop("Error!"), error = function(e) warning(e[[1]]))
#Warning message:
#In value[[3L]](cond) : Error!
library(testthat)
expect_warning(tryCatch(stop("Error!"), error = function(e) warning(e[[1]])))
#no further output
```